# Trouble creating a line chart with circle tooltip

Tags: d3.js

So, I'm trying to copy this [tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/alandunning/cfb7dcd7951826b9eacd54f0647f48d3). The goal in the end is to have a line graph with a circle that follows the x position of the mouse and stays on the line, with a tooltip displaying relevant data about that location on the line. The following is the code I have, I have made a few small changes to styles and an addition of a filled area below the line, but I don't believe that should make a difference in how this works:

```
var margin = {
            top: 20,
            left: 50,
            right: 50,
            bottom: 50
        },
        width = $element.innerWidth() - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 0.2 * width;

        var parseTime = d3.timeParse('%m/%d/%Y');
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = parseTime(d.date);
            d.price = +d.price;
        });

        var bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).left;

        var x = d3.scaleTime()
            .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d, i) {
                return d.date;
            }))
            .range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d, i) {
                return d.price;
            }))
            .range([height, 0]);

        var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
            .tickSizeOuter(0);
        var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
            .ticks(5)
            .tickSizeOuter(0);

        var area = d3.area()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
            .y0(height)
            .y1(function(d) { return y(d.price); });

        var line = d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.price); });

        var svg = d3.select('#priceChart')
            .append('svg')
                .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append('g')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

        svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'x axis')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
            .call(xAxis);

        svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'y axis')
            .call(yAxis);

        var areaSvg = svg.append('g');
        areaSvg.append('path')
            .attr('class', 'area')
            .attr('d', area(data))
            .style('opacity', 0.3);

        var lineSvg = svg.append('g');
        lineSvg.append('path')
            .attr('class', 'line')
            .attr('d', line(data));

        var focus = svg.append('g')
            .style('display', 'none');

        focus.append('circle')
            .attr('class', 'y')
            .style('fill', 'steelblue')
            .attr('r', 3);

        svg.append('rect')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
            .style('fill', 'none')
            .style('pointer-events', 'all')
            .on('mouseover', function() { focus.style('display', null); })
            .on('mouseout', function() { focus.style('display', 'none'); })
            .on('mousemove', mousemove);

        function mousemove() {
            var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
                i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
                d0 = data[i - 1],
                d1 = data[i],
                d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;

            focus.select('circle.y')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x(d.date) + ',' + y(d.price) + ')');
        }
```

I can't tell what I'm doing wrong. But basically when I move my mouse on the left half of the screen, absolutely nothing happens. The circle appears on the last data point in the graph and never moves. If I move my mouse on the right side of the graph I get an error in the console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'date' of undefined`.

**UPDATE**
Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o10z9svL/) representing the problem. The code I've provided is actually a function and both data and $element are passed in variables. I've changed how they are passed in in the fiddle, but the data is the same as what I'm working with.

Comment: can you attach a fiddle of what you've got? (basically include the html)

Comment: also, where is $element defined?

Comment: @deweyredman I've edited the question to include a jsFiddle and explained where both data and $element come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using `d3.bisector` you have to sort your data array first.

The API is not very explicit regarding this point, but you can read there:

> Returns the insertion point for x in array to maintain sorted order [...] The return value is suitable for use as the first argument to splice assuming that array is **already sorted**. (emphasis mine)

So, this is the function to sort your data, before you use `d3.bisector`:

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return d3.ascending(a.date, b.date)
});
```

Here is your working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7154p8uv/

Comment: That is awesome, totally missed that on my own. Thank you very much for your help.